# How can I access an objects properties that is wrapped in a Task<>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to access a property on the user within UpdateUser(userModelFromRepo), when I change the parameters to accept Task I cannot access the User.modifiedAt property. Is there a way to do so? Alternatively, is there a way to just return the user object back and remain async from GetUserById()? **await _repository.UpdateUser(userModelFromRepo)** says that it cannot convert from Task User to User.

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(int id, UserUpdateDto userUpdateDto)
    {
        var userModelFromRepo = _repository.GetUserById(id);
        if (userModelFromRepo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        await _mapper.Map(userUpdateDto, userModelFromRepo);
        await _repository.UpdateUser(userModelFromRepo);
        await _repository.SaveChanges();

        return NoContent();
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task UpdateUser(User userModelFromRepo)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }
            user.ModifiedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to await the call like this

```
var userModelFromRepo =  await _repository.GetUserById(id);
```

Full code:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(int id, UserUpdateDto userUpdateDto)
{
    var userModelFromRepo =  await _repository.GetUserById(id);
    if (userModelFromRepo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    await _mapper.Map(userUpdateDto, userModelFromRepo);
    await _repository.UpdateUser(userModelFromRepo);
    await _repository.SaveChanges();

    return NoContent();
}
```

Also, if you don't do anything else in your UpdateUser method you can remove the Task.Run stuff, it doesn't add any value.

```
public Task UpdateUser(User userModelFromRepo)
{
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        user.ModifiedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```